# Java toString method difference

Tags: java, integer, tostring

I enjoy CodeFights at the moment and at the end of my last fight i found something interesting. The code in those two cases (mine and the opponent) was said to be correct. Is there a difference between this source code:

```
return Integer.toString(Character.getNumericValue(ch1) + Character.getNumericValue(ch2));
```

and this one:

```
return new Integer(Character.getNumericValue(ch1)+ Character.getNumericValue(ch2)).toString();
```

What is the key that i am missing?

Comment: this is java and many ways drive you to Rom too... both return the same one is static called....

Comment: Note this is the same as `"" + (ch1 + ch2 - 2 * '0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

`String toString()`
   Returns a String object representing this Integer's value.

`static String toString(int i)`
   Returns a String object representing the specified integer.

Answer (score 1):

Integer's `toString` method is implemented as `Integer.toString(value)`, so the second answer merely has a redundant instantiation.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(value);
}
```